# d3js two svg, one external postitioning

Tags: d3.js, svg

Hey so I have taken code from two examples and am trying to get them to show on the same webpage.
Working jsfiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/s40ustz1/4/
The problem is, when I add the second svg element, all the nodes positioning goes wonky. 
The code I am trying to add is

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 220 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
// Adds the svg canvas
var chart2 = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/5987480/data2.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the valueline path.
chart2.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add the X Axis
chart2.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
chart2.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
});
```

The main example I have taken code from is.
http://bl.ocks.org/fhernand/9a9f93f2a6b0e83a9294

I have tried adding div containers but they didn't seem to help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own question eventually through enough trial and error + some research. The method which I used to append my external SVG file was causing the issues although I am not sure why. 
So instead of loading the document like this:

```
d3.xml("http://bl.ocks.org/fhernand/raw/9a9f93f2a6b0e83a9294/field.svg",     function (xml) {
svgdom = document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var defs = d3.select("defs");
```

I instead loaded it like this:

```
var main_map_div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div");

d3.xml("field.svg", function (error, documentFragment) {
if (error) {console.log(error); return;}
var svgNode = documentFragment
                .getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
main_map_div.node().appendChild(svgNode);
svg = main_map_div.select("svg")
```

If I had to take a guess as to why it works, it would probably be because I am now appending the svg file to a div, which I did not previously know how to do before.
Working jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/s40ustz1/7/

Note: css styling might be off, but it works!